# Multi Language Site in sharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a site in English and I have convert that site into Hindi what can be done to achieve this.
I thought of taking the backup of the site and create a site with language as Hindi will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Using Variations you can create multilingual site. 
Please check this blog for your reference.

http://netwovenblogs.com/2014/01/13/using-variations-to-create-multilingual-sites-in-sharepoint/